# Loosing current session when we click on hyper links

Tags: java, session

When I click on a hyper link the request goes another tomcat server and renders file content in another tab. But, the session getting timed out when I do any operation in first tab. Can anyone provide solution please?

Comment: Is there something about the two servers that would somehow affect the cookies of each other?

Comment: I guess so..when I send request to other server it might be creating new JSESSIONID and hence old server could not able to identify old session..not sure...

Comment: Easy to test.  Look at the cookies before and after clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sessions then you will need to ensure that the request always goes to the same tomcat server because the session is stored in memory on the server.  Your load balancer should have configuration to allow for setting up sticky sessions based on a cookie value.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP wants.  Madhu doesn't want to continue his session, he/she just doesn't want the file download to interfere with the current session.

Comment: If Madhu's download request goes through a load balancer (or reverse proxy) and is sent to a different tomcat instance that doesn't know about the current session and creates a new one then the JSESSIONID cookie is going to be overwritten with the new one from the download server because they all have the same domain. Further requests to the original (i.e. page load or even just ajax) will have a "bad" JSESSIONID from that point on and may look like the session timed out to the server. Sticky sessions would be one way to fix this. Of course, this would be easier answered if Madhu would clarify